# Images in flexslider not working responsively

Tags: responsive, flexslider, responsive-images

I would be really grateful for some help. I have a very limited understanding of HTML and am trying to customize this webpage template using HTML/css. My main issue is that when I add flexslider into the template following the instructions provided in the documentation support, the images I add to the template are not responsive. Here are the instructions for adding images to the slider:

````
    <div class="slides">
        <div class="flex-slide">

            [...]

        </div>
        <div class="flex-slide">

            [...]

        </div>
        <div class="flex-slide">

            [...]

        </div>
    </div>
</div>```

The section in which I am trying to add the images has the following code:

```<section class="section pt-180 pb-180 sm-pt-90 sm-pb-90">
            <div class="overlay">
                            <div class="overlay-wrapper parallax-wrapper">```

I apologise in advance if this a completely dumb dee dee dum dum question, but I am completely out of my depth here and any advice/help would be gratefully received.

Thank you in advance and Merry Christmas!
````

Answer (score 0):

i cant understand completely. it will help if you provide the code for those classes.

you can try setting padding to images and setting the min/max height and width to those images. you can also make the page responsive by adjusting its viewport.

if you are working with flexbox, this link can help to understand the property (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp).